# something wrong with rnpm for realm

Tags: react-native, realm

I could not install rnpm although npm is okay, it doesn't feel right when i run npm install -g rnpm. what's wrong with it?

> "npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "rnpm"
>   npm ERR! node v6.2.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local  /lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/pingguo-pc/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

run the terminal as the administrator, using command "sudo -s", then we can make it.